# Как добиться расширения без дублирования, когда применяется for?

Tags: java

Представим такую ситуацию, 
есть какой-то метод, его задача писать 10 раз привет и пока.

Но тут к нам приходят, говорят, требования изменились, нужно между привет и пока дописать что-нибудь еще...

У цикла for вообще есть подобная возможность для расширения? 
Если да, как это можно реализовать, без дублирования самого метода

```
void function(){
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println("привет"); 

    //  System.out.println("- это прелюдия перед"); // добавленная часть

        System.out.println("пока");
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы каким-либо образом изменить композицию кода, нужно сначала сделать его декомпозицию.

Comment: а про паттерн шаблонный метод читали?

Comment: Нет, посмотрю, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел еще раз на описанную проблему и посчитал, что она весьма актуальна и распространена, посему думаю, что уместно показать 2 наиболее корректных (с моей точки зрения) пути решения данной задачи.
Первый подход функциональный. Рассматривая ваш пример, я не понял, зачем вы создавали свой интерфейс, ведь в джаве, начиная с 8 версии, есть стандартный набор функциональных интерфейсов. Тот интерфейс, что написали вы,давно написан за вас и называется предикат. Тогда решение будет выглядеть так:

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t = new Test();

        Predicate<Integer> p1 = n -> {
            System.out.println(n);
            return true;
        };

        Predicate<Integer> p2 = n -> {
            System.out.println(n);
            return n < 5;
        };

        t.function(p1);
        System.out.println("*********************************");
        t.function(p2);
    }

    public void function(Predicate<Integer> inside) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("привет");
            if (inside != null && !inside.test(i)) break;
            System.out.println("пока");
        }
    }

}
```

Я специально создал два предиката и передал их поочередно в метод, чтобы было видно, что отрабатывают они по разному: первый выводит все значения перемнной i, второй - только значения меньше либо равные 5, после чего цикл прерывается условием в самом цикле. Таким образом, пердавая различные предикаты в аргументы метода, мы можете менять поведение внутри самого цикла. 
К сожалению, функциональный подход не всегда доступен и в любом случае хорошо бы понимать и альтернативу из ООП. Как я и писал, такая альтернатива называется шаблонным методом. Реализация тогда будет такова:

```
public abstract class Test {

    public void function() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("привет");
            if (!execute(i)) break;
            System.out.println("пока");
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean execute(Integer i);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().function();
        System.out.println("********************************************");
        new B().function();
    }

}

public class A extends Test {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(Integer n) {
        System.out.println(n);
        return true;
    }    
}

public class B extends Test {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(Integer n) {
        System.out.println(n);
        return n < 5;
    }    
}
```

Результат выполнения данного кода абсолютно аналогичен. Теперь наш класс Тест абстрактный и имеет 2 метода : абстрактный execute и реализованный function, в котором и написан наш цикл, и именно отсюда вызывается наш абстрактный метод. В этом и есть суть паттерна шаблонный метод - вызов абстрактного метода из уже реализованного. Ну и, разумеется, поскольку наш класс Тест абстрактный, мы не можем создать его экземпляр. Поэтому нам нужно унаследоваться от него. Поскольку в прошлом примере мы рассматривали создание 2 предикатов, что обеспечивало 2 различных вида поведений наше программы, то и здесь мы поступим аналогично, но теперь менять поведение будут наши наследники. Итак, создаем два класса А и В, наследуемся от нашего класса Тест и переопределяем единственный абстрактный метод, реализуя различное поведение для класса А и класса В. Теперь мы получим различное поведение системы при вызове метода родительского класса function в зависимости от того, экземпляр какого класса А или Б мы создадим.

Comment: Ваааа, спасибо за столь подробный ответ... Сохраню его отдельно, чтобы еще раз перечитать после того, как закончу с книжкой по ООП

Comment: @ i'mNasten'ka не за что, рад, что информация оказалась полезной. стараюсь писать расширенные ответы на наиболее интересные вопросы, правда времени на это не всегда хватает) если читаете про ооп, то, полагаю, будут инетересны 2 ответа, которые я писал относительно недавно: про паттерн шаблолнный метод и про реализацию обратной польской нотации (штука распространеная, однако, я удивился, что мне не удалось найти ни одной ООП реализации, пришлось набросать свою). ссылки прилагаю ниже

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1070800/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b/1071513#1071513

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1071057/factory-method-%d0%a4%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4/1071587#1071587

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface InsideLoop {
  boolean exec(int counter);
}

void function(InsideLoop inside) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("привет"); 

    if (inside != null) {
      if (!inside.exec(i)) {
        break;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("пока");
  }
}

function(null);

function(counter -> {
  System.out.println(counter);
  return true;
});

// или

public class InsideLoopImpl implements InsideLoop {
  @Override
  boolean exec(int counter) {
    System.out.println(counter);
  }
}
function(new InsideLoopImpl());
```

Comment: У меня нижнюю часть подчеркивает красным... Это лямбда-выражения? А можно без них? Просто...просто...я еще не умею с ними

Comment: Я добавила в конце скриншот, что подсвечивает

Comment: @i'mNasten'ka Это просто вызовы функции. Их надо поместить внутри другого метода.

Comment: @i'mNasten'ka исправил ошибку в `if (!inside.exec(i)) {`

Comment: У меня последний абзац все равно подчеркивается, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Или хотя бы ссылку на какой-нибудь Ideone, где можно было бы увидеть, что это работает

Comment: @i'mNasten'ka https://onlinegdb.com/B1ukUGMlU

Comment: @i'mNasten'ka Подчеркивает, потому что вы вышли за пределы метода, в котором можно что-то сделать.

Comment: Хорошо, большое спасибо Вам