# return не действует на наследника (Java)

Tags: java, методы, условия, return

Доброе время суток. Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что у меня есть родительский класс и его наследник. В родительском классе у меня стоит условие `if(isPaused) return;` - т.е. если переменная isPaused = true, то метод должен прерываться. Но при этом в наследнике я вызываю super этого метода, и часть родительского метода не срабатывает, как и надо, а у наследника все продолжает работать. Может кто-то встречался с этой проблемой и знает как её решить?

[image: Наследник] [image: Родитель]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос классы о которых вы говорте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никакой проблемы в этом нет, если вы переопределяете метод, и в нем вызываете super(), то супер в этом месте и отрабатывает, но если у вас в переопределенном методе должно тоже что-то остановиться, то в нем так же делайте проверку `if(isPaused) return;` в нужном для вас месте. 
Используйте паттерн шаблонный метод.

```
 public sclass Helper extends HeS{
     public void act(float){
         super.act(delta);
         if(GameScreen.setPause) return;
         templateMethod();
     }

     public void templateMethod(){
     }
 }
```

в наследниках переопределяете templateMethod().

Шаблонный метод может быть абстрактный, может иметь реализацию по умолчанию - по необходимости. Абстрактным вы его можете сделать только в абстрактном классе. Преимущество абстрактного метода в том, что нельзя унаследовать класс не переопределив этот метод - компилятор будет ругаться.

Comment: Но нельзя как-нибудь сделать, чтобы мне не нужно было проверять? Т.к. у меня 10 наследников, и в каждом делать проверку не хочется

Comment: добавьте пример или ссылку на github, без кода вам с этим вряд ли помогут

Comment: Добавил, все лишнее убрал

Comment: добавил пример использования шаблонного метода

Comment: @Z.John для того, чтобы в вашем ответе появилась реализация паттерна шаблонный метод, необходимо , чтобы метод templateMethod был абстрактный, иначе вы просто из одного метода класса вызываете другой метод класса.

Comment: @Z.John вот, посмотрите мой ответ здесь, как раз описана реализация этого паттерна https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066924/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-for

Comment: Он может быть абстрактный, может иметь реализацию по умолчанию - по необходимости. абстрактным вы его можете сделать только в абстрактном классе. Преимущество абстрактного метода в том, что нельзя унаследовать класс не переопределив этот метод - компилятор будет  ругаться.

Comment: `templateMethod` надо вызывать после проверки, тогда в нем ничего проверять не нужно

Comment: @Igor В примере хотел показать просто подход к решению таких ситуаций. Но в контексте вопроса вы правы - поправил ответ